# input different nchar vector and output into four digit

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, paste

I would like to write a function that a vector randomly goes to one to four digit and I would like to print it out all into four digits, if there are not enough number of character in the vector, I would like to add 0 in front of that vector.

```
Input:
x <- 1
x <- 12
x <- 123
x <- 1234

Output:
numb(x)
0001
numb(x)
0012
numb(x)
0123
numb(x)
1234

numb <- function(x) {{if(nchar(x) =4) { print(x) } 
else if (nchar(x) < 4) { y <- 4 - nchar(x) 
paste(nchar(y),x,sep="")}
}
```

I don't know how to make 1 into 0, 2 into 00 and 3 into 000 and then put it into the paste function.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` and specify the `fmt` to have leading zeros (`%04d`)

```
f1 <- function(num){
   sprintf("%04d", num)
}

f1(c(1, 12, 123, 1234))
#[1] "0001" "0012" "0123" "1234"
```

NOTE: A leading zero number is of `character` class and not `numeric/integer`